# deployment history is short in on openshift online pro

Tags: openshift, openshift-online

The command `oc describe dc/backend` is only showing the last three deployments. Due to a troublesome rollout, the last three deployments today were the same code. Is it possible to see a longer history of deployments to make it easier to see the one we want to deploy with `oc rollback backend --to-version=X`?

Answer (score 0):

In first, you need to check your current revisionHisoryLimit from your deploymentConfig resource using `oc get dc/backend -o yaml`. [0] And edit it for your needs.

[0]No circle 7[https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html#creating-a-deployment-configuration]